# Behaviour of Artin $L$-function at pole larger than 3/2

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions

I am trying to read this paper [Poles of Artin $L-$functions and the strong Artin conjecture](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v158-n3-p11.pdf)

On page $1095,$ we are trying to estimate the integral $$\int L(s, \rho) e^{i(\pi/2 - \delta ) s} (2 \pi )^{-s} \Gamma (s - 3/2) E_{-1}(s) ds$$

where $L(s, \rho)$ is Artin $L$-function with 2-dimensional, icosahedral representation $\rho$.

By shifting the contour of the integral to $\mathrm{Re} (s) = 3/2 + \Delta$ with $0 < \Delta < 1/2$, the paper says that the integrand is $\mathrm{O} \left(\frac{1}{|s|^{3/2 - \Delta} } \right)$.

I am trying to figure out how he came to the conclusion that the integrand is $\mathrm{O} \left(\frac{1}{|s|^{3/2 - \Delta} } \right)$.

It is given in Lemma $3$ that $E_{-1}(s)$ is $\mathrm{O} (1/s)$ in $\mathrm{Re} (s) > 1$.

We can use the Stirling formula for the gamma function in the integral above. But I have no idea how to bound the Artin $L$-function in the integral above.

For the integrand to be $\mathrm{O} \left(\frac{1}{|s|^{3/2 - \Delta} } \right),$ it seems like $L(s, \rho) = \mathrm{O} (\frac{1}{s^k})$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ has to be true. I am not sure whether it is true that $L(s, \rho) = \mathrm{O} (\frac{1}{s^k})$, $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ or how to derive this expression even if it's true.

How can I eventually derive the bound $\mathrm{O} (\frac{1}{|s|^{3/2 - \Delta} } )$ for the integrand? I just started reading about Artin $L$-functions, so I might have missed some basic properties.

Comment: For $\Re(s) = 3/2 + \Delta$, we have that $L(s,\rho) = O(1)$, $e^{i(\pi/2 - \delta)s} = O(1)$, $(2\pi)^{-s} = O(1)$, $\Gamma(s - 3/2) = O(|s|^{\Delta - 1/2})$, and $E_{-1}(s) = O(|s|^{-1})$. So the integrand is $O(|s|^{\Delta - 3/2})$. Note that $L(s,\rho) = O(1)$ follows trivially by bounding the absolutely convergent Dirichlet series term by term.